# Can I drive a 2560x1600 display with a 1920x1080 signal?

Tags: resolution, hdmi, hdtv

I want to buy a lcd back-lit led monitor for use as a TV, by connecting a full-hd digital receiver to led via HDMI. I planned to buy [this dell-u3011](http://www.dell.com/ed/business/p/dell-u3011/pd) led monitor for this purpose, but I am a little confused. Its resolution is 2560x1600, but I want to watch tv at 1920x1080. Please tell me if this is possible? My required output is FHD, will any other resolution greater than 1920x1080 will support to FHD(1920x1080)?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is yes.
The long answer is that most(all?) monitors will have some level of backwards compatibility in terms of resolution. This means that a monitor with a maximum resolution of 1920x1080 will also work at 1280x720. This should apply in your case where the monitor is capable of delivering 2560x1600 resolution.
The problem you will encounter however is that because the 2 resolutions(2560x1600 and 1920x1080) have different aspect ratios you will probably end up with some dark areas on the sides of the screen.
UPDATE:
There are other possible behaviours when not using the native monitor resolution and/or aspect ratio such as stretching. This is more specific to older or low-cost monitors but since your monitor is neither old or low-cost you should be fine.

Comment: It’s actually more likely the image will be stretched, especially with lowish-cost monitors. The U3011 display offers an option to control this.

Answer (score 0):

> "...but I want to watch tv at 1920x1080. Please tell me if this is possible?"

You can run this display at a lower resolution, as it supports HDMI it will downscale. This may not be advisable though. This display is 16:10 aspect ratio, so the scaling down to 1920x1080 may look odd. Your aim is for 1920x1080 which is 16:9 aspect ratio this display is 16:10.

1920x1080 - 16:9

1920x1200 - 16:10

2560x1600 - 16:10

Comment: Actually, it’s upscaling, by the way.

Answer (score -1):

OP: "but i want to watch tv at 1920x1080. please tell me that this is possible???" ME: Yes, it is possible for that monitor to display that resolution.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/481379)

Comment: 2 questions were asked, one was answered. 

Thank you